# Contact future line manager when going on vacation before starting job

Tags: professionalism, communication, new-job, vacation

I'm starting my new job in January. Last week I signed the contract, now currently going through HR background checks. I'm planning to go on holiday for two weeks - is it necessary to email future line manager and headhunter to let them know, in case they need to get hold of me. Is it a good idea to start a dialog with the line manager, considering we went for coffee last week and she said contact her if I have any problems.

Answer (score 7):

A short (!) email would definitely be appropriate and appreciated, especially if you can provide contact details (cell phone?) where you would be available for any last-minute things that come up.

Answer (score 0):

This depends I think. Will you be without internet and your phone during that time? If so, then a quick email giving a heads up saying you'll be without access to phone or email from this date to that date would be good. Provide a back up means to reach you if required.

If you'll have access to them though, just let it be. More than likely, they will be heading off on holidays soon too, and not much work will be getting done.